# Creating an array from a form posted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I post a "select" parameter via a form (and other fields)

My Model needs an ARRAY of the parent_musicstyle parameter, but gets an string.

Where and how do I convert this?
In the View, Controller or Model

Form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :parent_musicstyle %>
    <%= f.select :parent_musicstyle,
                  Musicstyle.all.map { |m| [m.musicstyle, m._id] },
                  {:include_blank => "Select a parent (if needed)", :index => nil } %>
</div>
```

How can I extract/convert the specific param and convert it to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your model `musicstyle`, and you'd have:

```
<%= form_for :musicstyle do |f| 
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then, in your controller, you can do

```
pm = params[musictyle][parent_musicstyle]
pm = [pm]
```

That said, you'd have an array of one element, which is not useful. Is your select a multiple selection one?

Comment: Hi Wawa,no, it's simply a dropdown

Comment: So you need an array with one element only?

Comment: yes.. correct.. :-)
But for future usage a example for checkboxes will also very helpful..

Comment: params are always sent as string. You need to convert them to whatever your want if the implicit conversion from Rails does not work. Nothing to do with checkbox.

Comment: Did it work for you? If it did, please accept the answer. Cheers!